# Translate Docker-compose to Kubernetes service node app

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, npm, docker-compose

this is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs:
    build: ./
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I have 2 images, 1 - pm2 ( node.js ) images which start  3000 ports, and the second image is Nginx, where I `proxy_pass` node app

Now, my purpose is to deploy this in k8s. can anyone explain how to do this? In docker-compose is working good.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to explore [translate-compose-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/)?

```
 kompose convert
---
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-service.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nextjs-deployment.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-deployment.yaml" created
```

and it will convert it to Kubernetes manifest.
then do apply

```
kubectl apply -f .
```

The only change that will be required is to build and push images, the above `docker-compose` build those images locally and then run.

But for Kubernetes, you need to push those to the [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry)

Also, you do not need the Nginx proxy, better to use [nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and route traffic to nodejs app.